# Angular variable binding not working on page/browser reload but works while navigating through routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a subscribe button which has `Subscribe` text written on it. The problem is when the page reload the Subscribe value is not shown. The value of button is controlled by typescript code. The strange thing is when i navigate to any route the text magically appears.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" (click)="subscribe()" name="subscribe" id="subscribe">
    <span *ngIf="!subscribeFormProcessing">Subscribe</span>
    <span *ngIf="subscribeFormProcessing"><img [src]="btnLoaderUrl"></span>
</button>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class FooterWidgetComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    subscribeEmailAddress: string;
    subscribeEmailSubscriber: any;
    btnLoaderUrl: string;
    subscribeFormProcessing = false;
    subscribeMsg: string;

    constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService, private httpRequestService: HttpRequestService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscribeEmailAddress = '';
        this.subscribeMsg = '';
        this.btnLoaderUrl = this.appSettingsService.getImagesBaseUrl() + 'app/btn-loader.gif';
        this.subscribeEmailSubscriber = this.httpRequestService.requestCompleted.subscribe(data => {
            this.subscribeFormProcessing = false;
            if (data['status'] === "success") {
                this.subscribeMsg = data['message'];
            } else {
                this.subscribeMsg = data['message'];
            }
            this.clearSubscribeMessage()
        });
    }

    clearSubscribeMessage() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.subscribeMsg = '';
        }, 5000);
    }

    subscribe() {
        this.subscribeFormProcessing = true;
        this.httpRequestService.setUrl('subscribe');
        this.httpRequestService.sendPost({email: this.subscribeEmailAddress});
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscribeEmailSubscriber.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

**On Page Reload**

[image: On Page Load]

**After navigating to any route**

[image: After navigation]

**Root Cause**
I am using Addthis widget for sharing post and blog. On the blog page loads I initialize the addthis which is causing this particular issue.

```
initAddThisToolbar() {
        addthis.layers.refresh();
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox"></div>
```

Is there any other method through which I can refresh addthis widget.

Comment: add your type script in app.component.ts or any page where your routing is start   onInIt method

Comment: @bhaumikshah that didn't help

Comment: can you post your typescript?

Comment: @bhaumikshah `initAddThisToolbar` is called in ngOnInit(). Thats the only code there

Answer (score 0):

When the page refreshes it does not call `onDestroy()`. So your description never gets dropped, `this.httpRequestService.requestCompleted.subscribe()`doesn't get called a second time, although `onInit()`is processed, and that's why `this.subscribeFormProcessing` stays `true`.

You have to find a way to unsubscribe() this.subscribeEmailSubscriber during reload. Do something like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   // check whether there is already an active subscription
   // if so, drop it.
   if (this.subscribeEmailSubscriber) {
       this.subscribeEmailSubscriber.unsubscribe();
   }

   // the rest of the code stays as is
   this.subscribeEmailAddress = '';
   this.subscribeMsg = '';
   this.btnLoaderUrl = this.appSettingsService.getImagesBaseUrl() + 'app/btn-loader.gif';
   this.subscribeEmailSubscriber = this.httpRequestService.requestCompleted.subscribe(data => {
        this.subscribeFormProcessing = false;
        if (data['status'] === "success") {
            this.subscribeMsg = data['message'];
        } else {
            this.subscribeMsg = data['message'];
        }
        this.clearSubscribeMessage()
   });
}
```